# Update in transaction SQLite3 and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I update rows in user table (sqlite3 and Python) with

```
def update_user_by_id(self,id,first_name,last_name,username,password,privilege,email):
    '''Update user in table user based on id on passed parameters'''
    try:
        connection=sqlite3.connect(self.__path_users)
        cursor=connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''UPDATE user SET first_name=?,last_name=?,username=?,password=?,privilege=?,email=? where id=?''',first_name,last_name,username,password,privilege,email,id)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        print "Affected: %d", cursor.rowcount
    except sqlite3.Error, e:
        print "Ooops:", e.args[0]
```

but how to put this into transaction ?

Comment: Can you add more description to your question..

Answer (score 1):

This is already a transaction.  The transaction is commited when you call `connection.commit()`.  If you would like to roll it back just remove that line.

Comment: I have two app, on on C which read from database and this Python which update, insert and delete. I want to put this stuff in transaction, so C app canot read wrong.

Comment: @AlmiraBojani It is a transaction, although it's just a single operation already. And it is ACID. You'll need to elaborate if there's another problem.